# Including a folder of css/js files in jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a set of common css/js files for my application in two folders say commoncss and commonjs in a folder(u_i) inside my webroot. I am including them as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${commonResourcePath}/commonjs/dsf.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="${commonResourcePath}/commonjs/sdc.js"></script>

.

.

<script type="text/javascript" src="${commonResourcePath}/commonjs/eee.js"></script>
```

But I would like to include all files in a folder automatically by just giving the folder path
like

```
<myinclude:allfiles folderName="${commonResourcePath}/commonjs"/>
```

Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find something that do this, but i haven't found. So, i think nobody did that yet.

If you really need it, you can create your own jsp tag that will do it for you.

Some tutorials on google: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=creating+custom+jsp+tag

Comment: Ok. Remember to set as answer if nobody comes ;)